# missing scott schema in Oracle XE

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, schema, oracle-xe

I have downloaded [Oracle XE 11.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) and successfully installed on my Windows machine. But, I didn't find `Scott` schema in it. During installation, I didn't get any option where it asked to create sample schema. Could anyone suggest how to get `scott` schema in Oracle XE 11.2 ?

**List of users :**

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question. I didn't get any option to create sample schema during installation. So, This doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have imported `SCOTT` schema using following script

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\scott.sql
```

Then I reset the password for this user using

```
alter user scott identified by tiger;
```

Now, I was able to login to `scott` and able to use existing table like `EMP`, `DEPT` etc..